# Intellij Smart Tomcat Plugin

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, war, tomcat9

I was using the SmartTomcat plugin on Intellij Community Edition, I set the deployment directory to the wtpwebapps in the Tomcat 9 folder, and after running the smart tomcat configuration, I was able to access my webapplication, but there are no files in the wtpwebapps directory. Where can I get the files that have been deployed by smart tomcat? Should I find an exploded war in wtpwebapps or no?

In eclipse external tomcat deployment is possible, when I did the same on eclipse I found the war module has been deployed to the path I have specified unlike SmartTomcat plugin of Intellij.

Comment: Found out that the SmartTomcat will auto load the Webapp classes and libs from project and module, it will not copy the classes and libs to the WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: what do you mean by WEB-INF? can you provide a picture of the directory you are speaking of?